# Left Join two table with Partition by and some specific condition

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I would like to join two table one table is the actual table data and the other table is the review table in which I am reviewing something I want to join the two table on dates condition.
Table 1 is having a large number of data with account_id,Partner_id,Dates and actual_review.
Review Table is the table having data with account_id,Partner_id,Date of review and review_recommended.

What I am doing is taking an account and doing the review of the account and adding that review in review_recommended.

```
Table 1:  
Id_partner | Id_account |    Date    |  actual_review  
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/23 |     Good        
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/25 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/27 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/31 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/10 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/14 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/16 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/12 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/15 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/18 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/25 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/05 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/06 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/09 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/12 |     Good    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/15 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/18 |     Bad    
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/20 |     Good
```

I take some account and than do their review that wether it was Good or Bad
and will have a different table with these reviews I do reviewing for an account after some interval, say if I did review of account today I may do the review of the account after sometime or someday

```
Review Table :  
Id_partner | Id_account | Date_review |  review_recommended  
   4       |   7009     | 2018/12/22  |     Good   
   4       |   7009     | 2019/01/20  |     Bad  
   4       |   7009     | 2019/02/16  |     Good  
   4       |   7009     | 2019/03/12  |     Bad
```

I would like to join two table in such a way that until I review it again I need the review_recommended to be same till the next

I tried doing it with Left Join but it makes difficult as it joins most of the rows

```
Table After Joining :
Id_partner | Id_account |    Date    |  actual_review | review_recommended  
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/23 |     Good       |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/25 |     Good       |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/27 |     Good       |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2018/12/31 |     Bad        |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/10 |     Good       |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/14 |     Good       |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/01/16 |     Bad        |      Good  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/12 |     Good       |      Bad  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/15 |     Good       |      Bad  
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/18 |     Bad        |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/02/25 |     Bad        |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/05 |     Bad        |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/06 |     Good       |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/09 |     Good       |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/12 |     Good       |      Good   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/15 |     Bad        |      Bad   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/18 |     Bad        |      Bad   
    4      |   7009     | 2019/03/20 |     Good       |      Bad
```

Joining is done on id_accounts, id_partners , Date and Date_review as we are having many account and partners in the table.
Any guidance or help appreciated!

Comment: Mysql and postgresql are two different prducts with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: which version of mysql you are  using ?

Comment: Sorry I am not using mysql I just wanted to have the logic of sql for the above problem

Comment: So, which DBMS product **are** you using?

Comment: I am using postgressql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this issue in mysql 
test1 is your Table 1
and test2 is your Review Table.

> IT can better be solve with row_nmber  easily

but as you don't define your database version and name this one better solution

```
select d.*,test1.actual_review, test2.review_recommended
FROM test2
inner join 
(
SELECT dates,
       Id_partner,
       Id_account,
       MAX(Date_review) AS Date_review
FROM (SELECT test1.*, test2.`Date_review`, test2.`review_recommended`
      FROM test1
           LEFT JOIN test2
              ON     test2.`Id_account` = test1.`Id_account`
                 AND test2.`Id_partner` = test1.`Id_partner`
      WHERE test1.Dates > test2.`Date_review`) DATA
GROUP BY dates, Id_partner, Id_account )d
ON test2.Date_review =d.Date_review 
inner join test1 on d.dates = test1.dates and d.Id_account = test1.Id_account and d.Id_partner = test1.Id_partner;
```

> EDIT 1 using row_number

```
select * from (
select  data.*,row_number() over (partition by  Id_account,Id_partner,dates  order by Date_review desc  ) as sr_no from 
(SELECT test1.*, test2.`Date_review`, test2.`review_recommended`
      FROM test1
           LEFT JOIN test2
              ON     test2.`Id_account` = test1.`Id_account`
                 AND test2.`Id_partner` = test1.`Id_partner`
      WHERE test1.Dates > test2.`Date_review`) as data) as d 
      where d.sr_no =1;
```

Comment: Can you also provide the solution with the row_number partition by function?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked totally fine for me.Really appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
  A.Id_partner ,A.Id_account ,A.Date,A.actual_review  ,B.review_recommended  
FROM table1 AS A
  LEFT JOIN Review AS B
  ON A.Id_account  = B.Id_account 
  AND A.Id_partner = B.Id_partner
```

Comment: But don't you think its improper as we are joining on A.Date = B.Date_review whereas we are not having any Date_review same as Date?

Comment: But I still think it is a wrong way as it will join whole table in all possible way and we will end up with more rows in the new table.  Can you please read my above question what I needed